# KnockoutJS Search filter not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using javascript and knockoutjs to implement a search filter using the viewmodel .I am not able to get the search filter to work.below is my js file

```
//Object Constructor Class for Locations
var Locations = function (title, lat, lng, id, marker){

  this.title = title;
  this.lat = lat;
  this.lng  = lng;
  this.id = id;
  this.marker = marker;
};

var viewModel = {
  locations : [
    new Locations('The Travel Cafe',  51.499542,  -0.114134,  '57540ed1498ef7771538048d'),
    new Locations('Scooter Caffè',  51.50050110129609,  -0.11393191896812872,  '4ace5183f964a520d5cf20e3'),
    new Locations('Four Corners',  51.50042544028603,  -0.11365986202011345,  '51e52b0b498e1d7ea31d88c1'),
    new Locations('The Library Lounge at Marriott County Hall',  51.50193765161251,  -0.12006535004714862, '543148b9498ec4159f277ce6'),
    new Locations('Coleman Coffee Roasters',  51.500636,  -0.112947,  '57025a60498e2196f62e9548')
  ],

  searchBox: ko.observable('')

};

viewModel.search = ko.computed(function() {
  var self = this;
  var searchResult = this.searchBox().toLowerCase();

  return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.locations, function(markerLocation) {
            var title = markerLocation.title.toLowerCase();
            var matched = title.indexOf(searchResult) > -1;
            var marker = markerLocation.marker;
            if (marker) {
                marker.setVisible(matched);
            }
            //when I console.log(markerLocation.marker) i get undefined
            return matched;
      });
    }, viewModel);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

here is the html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset= "utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Neighbourhood Project</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class=".container">
        <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search for locations" data-bind:"value: searchBox">
      <ul data-bind="foreach: search">
        <li data-bind="text: title "></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/knockout-3.4.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/map.js"></script>
    <script async defer type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDRb_wXWOfFjBhfbUaH7NYcON4gSIa4wKo&v=3&callback=initMap"></script>
</body>
</html
```

i have tried to declare the locations[ ] array in the viewmodel as an ko.observableArray(). but it didn't work.can someone figure out what could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me after fixing three syntax problems:

- Two `</body>` tags.
- `</html>`instead of `<html`
- `data-bind="value: searchBox"` instead of `data-bind:"value: searchBox"`

See https://jsfiddle.net/twzn3jmu/6/.

Nevertheless it's super lame.

EDIT: Found the reason for the bad performance.
"value" is a bad binding for inputs, use "textInput" instead.

See https://jsfiddle.net/twzn3jmu/8/

and http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html